# Cloudify manager bootsrapping - rest service failed

Tags: cloudify

I followed the steps in http://docs.getcloudify.org/4.1.0/installation/bootstrapping/#option-2-bootstrapping-a-cloudify-manager to bootstrap the cloudify manager using option 2, and getting the following error repeatedly:

```
Workflow failed: Task failed 'fabric_plugin.tasks.run_script' -> restservice 
 error: http: //127.0.0.1:8100: <urlopen error [Errno 111] Connection refused>
```

The command is able to install a verify a lot of things like rabbitmq, postgresql etc, but always fails at rest service. Create and configure of rest service is successful, but verification fails. It looks like the service never starts.

```
2017-08-22 04:23:19.700  CFY <manager> [rest_service_cyd4of.start] Task started 'fabric_plugin.tasks.run_script'
2017-08-22 04:23:20.506  LOG <manager> [rest_service_cyd4of.start] INFO: Starting Cloudify REST Service...
2017-08-22 04:23:21.011  LOG <manager> [rest_service_cyd4of.start] INFO: Verifying Rest service is running...
2017-08-22 04:23:21.403  LOG <manager> [rest_service_cyd4of.start] INFO: Verifying Rest service is working as expected...
2017-08-22 04:23:21.575  LOG <manager> [rest_service_cyd4of.start] WARNING: <urlopen error [Errno 111] Connection refused>, Retrying in 3 seconds...
2017-08-22 04:23:24.691  LOG <manager> [rest_service_cyd4of.start] WARNING: <urlopen error [Errno 111] Connection refused>, Retrying in 6 seconds...
2017-08-22 04:23:30.815  LOG <manager> [rest_service_cyd4of.start] WARNING: <urlopen error [Errno 111] Connection refused>, Retrying in 12 seconds...
[10.0.2.15] out: restservice error: http: //127.0.0.1:8100: <urlopen error [Errno 111] Connection refused>
[10.0.2.15] out: Traceback (most recent call last):
[10.0.2.15] out:   File "/tmp/cloudify-ctx/scripts/tmp4BXh2m-start.py-VHYZP1K3", line 71, in <module>
[10.0.2.15] out:     verify_restservice(restservice_url)
[10.0.2.15] out:   File "/tmp/cloudify-ctx/scripts/tmp4BXh2m-start.py-VHYZP1K3", line 34, in verify_restservice
[10.0.2.15] out:     utils.verify_service_http(SERVICE_NAME, url, headers=headers)
[10.0.2.15] out:   File "/tmp/cloudify-ctx/scripts/utils.py", line 1734, in verify_service_http
[10.0.2.15] out:     ctx.abort_operation('{0} error: {1}: {2}'.format(service_name, url, e))
[10.0.2.15] out:   File "/tmp/cloudify-ctx/cloudify.py", line 233, in abort_operation
[10.0.2.15] out:     subprocess.check_call(cmd)
[10.0.2.15] out:   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 542, in check_call
[10.0.2.15] out:     raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
[10.0.2.15] out: subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['ctx', 'abort_operation', 'restservice error: http: //127.0.0.1:8100: <urlopen error [Errno 111] Connection refused>']' returned non-zero exit status 1
[10.0.2.15] out: 

Fatal error: run() received nonzero return code 1 while executing!

Requested: source /tmp/cloudify-ctx/scripts/env-tmp4BXh2m-start.py-VHYZP1K3 && /tmp/cloudify-ctx/scripts/tmp4BXh2m-start.py-VHYZP1K3
Executed: /bin/bash -l -c "cd /tmp/cloudify-ctx/work && source /tmp/cloudify-ctx/scripts/env-tmp4BXh2m-start.py-VHYZP1K3 && /tmp/cloudify-ctx/scripts/tmp4BXh2m-start.py-VHYZP1K3"
```

I am using CentOS 7.
Any suggestion to address the issue or debug will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try the same bootstrap option using [these instructions](https://github.com/cloudify-examples/cloudify-environment-setup/tree/latest) and let me know if it works for you?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the `python-virtualenv` package installed? If you do, try uninstalling it.

The version of virtualenv in CentOS repositories is too old and causes problems with the REST service installation. Cloudify will install its own version of virtualenv while bootstrapping, but only if one is not already present in the system.